# Why the two results are different?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to evaluate $\int_C\dfrac{z+1}{z^2+9}$ where $C$ is a positively oriented simple closed contour containning $z=\pm3i.$

- **Method 1:** Let $f(z)=\dfrac{z+1}{z^2+9}.$ Then the given integral is equal to $2\pi i\text{ Res}_{z=0}\dfrac{1}{z^2}f\left(\dfrac{1}{z}\right)$$=2\pi i\text{ Res}_{z=0}\dfrac{z(z+1)}{9z^2+1}=0$ since $\dfrac{z(z+1)}{9z^2+1}$ being analytic at $0$ it has a taylor series representation about $0$ so that the coefficient of $\dfrac{1}{z}$ is $0.$
- **Method 2:** $f(z)=\dfrac{\phi_1(z)}{z-3i}$ where $\phi_1(z)=\dfrac{z+1}{z+3i}$ is analytic and non-zero at $z=3i.$ So $f$ has a simple pole at $3i$ and $\text{Res}_{z=3i}f(z)=\phi_1(3i)=(3i+1)/6i=(3-i)/6$

  Similarly $\text{Res}_{z=3i}f(z)=(3+i)/6$

  So the given integral equal $2\pi i\times$sum of residues $=2\pi i$

Why the two results are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first method, you forgot to divide by ${z^2}$ after finding $f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$.

The correct function is $\frac{z+1}{z(9z+1)}$, and multiplying by $z$ then setting $z=0$ shows that the residue is $1$, as expected.